# Как правильно написать в официальном документе?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно написать в официальном документе: «Собираются прогнозные сведения об окончании плана, а впоследствии сотрудники собирают текущие сведения по выполнению прогноза»?

Answer (score 1):

При составлении предложения надо учитывать принятую сочетаемость слов. К примеру, фактически отсутствуют или редко применяются такие выражения, как ***прогнозные сведения, выполнение прогноза***. Стиль должен быть информативным: максимальный объем необходимой  информация при минимальном объеме текста, а также отсутствие информации ненужной.

Возможное редактирование:

**Сначала определяются прогнозные расчеты по срокам выполнения плана, а затем собираются текущие сведения о соответствии прогноза реальным показателям.**

Answer (score 0):

Могу высказать своё мнение, потому что здесь можно спорить очень долго и предлагать массу вариантов. Я предложу свои.
"Собираются прогнозирующие сведения об окончании плана. После чего, сотрудники составляют текущую характеристику составления прогноза"
"Собираются сведения, которые составят прогноз окончания плана. Впоследствии сотрудники собирают информацию, характеризующую текущий ход составления прогноза"

Answer (score 0):

Для начала постарайтесь разбить фразу на две. Пока смысл несколько затуманен. 
Хорошо бы ещё понять, что вообще за предметная область имеется в виду. План - это как в на производстве и в торговле, т.е. набор целевых показателей или типа "план мероприятий"?

Ну попробум порассуждать вообще.

Что могу сказать... План не оканчивается, а выполняется, а прогноз - оправдывается или нет. Так что речь в первой части скорее всего идёт о **сроках выполнения**, а вот во второй - сказать трудно. Если речь идёт всё-таки о выполнении плана (а не прогноза), то как-то так:

**Сначала собираются прогнозные сведения о сроках выполнения плана. Впоследствии сотрудники собирают текущие сведения об исполнении плана-прогноза.**
Но, повторюсь, это от желаемого смысла зависит.